# Theorems of euclidean geometry as invariable properties of geometric configurations

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, invariance

Is there some book, or systematic theory, that proves theorems
of euclidean geometry by viewing them as invariable properties
of certain geometric configurations ?

So that from an easy special case,
because of invariance, we conclude the
validity of the more difficult general case.

(Like, for example, in http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/morley.pdf
where Morley's theorem is proved with fixed points and group theory.)

Comment: The standard works are the four volumes by I M Yaglom, Geometric Transformations. Sounds great, but unfortunately many of the standard Euclidean geometry results are hard to prove that way (or maybe we have just got used to the more traditional style of proof because it is in all the textbooks and so insufficient effort has been put into this kind of proof).